# How to remove outlier from rows of a data frame having multiple column with similar name?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, outliers

I've a dataframe with multiple columns(around 300, here i have posted only five) having similar name and it looks like something like this:

```
   wave          rv           rv           rv           rv          rv                                                                      
4050.32  516.046391  1177.388115   291.478871   667.855218  139.966111   
4512.99  523.027066  1121.650093   304.243851   366.686912   21.157569   
4523.40  653.480487  1258.712111   565.797456   685.889408  211.022502   
4551.65  543.679071  1170.182836   615.175059   538.739229  217.254275   
4554.46  613.018264  1218.368040   512.241826   580.040475  148.860819   
4555.49  660.986074  1310.192328   727.650639   652.957370  241.255968
```

Now if i try to calculate the `MAD`or `MEDIAN` of the each row than it gets affected by the outliers.

```
df['mean_rv']=df.rv.mean(axis=1)
df['mad_rv']=df.rv.mad(axis=1)
df['std_rv']=df.rv.std(axis=1)
df['median_rv']=df.rv.median(axis=1)


wave        mean_rv      mad_rv      std_rv   median_rv                                                                    
4050.32  205.140781  515.455058  675.407100  402.282291   
4512.99  185.022378  527.156411  694.815800  388.641627   
4523.40  305.709437  508.197990  656.888951  565.797456   
4551.65  245.231088  510.966951  663.052403  479.494050   
4554.46  249.040192  546.425471  707.440193  496.937762   
4555.49  354.556840  510.052320  658.062092  586.095377
```

So what if i want to remove the outliers from the data frame then how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you exclude anywhere in general - define the threshold, usually in terms of the STD, and apply the filter:

```
mean = df.rv.mean(axis=1)
std  = df.rv.std(axis=1)
new_mean = df.rv[abs(df.rv.subtract(mean,axis=0)).lt(std,axis=0)].mean(axis=1)
```

In the `lt` you can define `std`, `2*std` etc., depending on what is an outlier. Note

```
df.rv[abs(df.rv.subtract(mean,axis=0)).lt(std,axis=0)]
```

will contain `nan` values where your outliers are, and `mean` and the similar methods omit these by default.

Answer (score 1):

You could do simple outlier detection using inner quartile range(IQR) . From wikipedia

> The interquartile range (IQR), also called the midspread or middle 50%, or technically H-spread, is a measure of statistical dispersion, being equal to the difference between 75th and 25th percentiles, or between upper and lower quartiles, IQR = Q3 − Q1.
>   In other words, the IQR is the first quartile subtracted from the third quartile; these quartiles can be clearly seen on a box plot on the data.
>   It is a measure of the dispersion similar to standard deviation or variance, but is much more robust against outliers.

```
Q1 = data.quantile(0.25)
Q3 = data.quantile(0.75)
IQR = Q3 - Q1
print(IQR)
if(data[i] < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) |(data[i] > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR))
    #outlier detected 
    #do stuff ...
```

if the data point is lying outside the outlier boundaries then the data point is possibly an outlier. So in your case based on the logic, you calculate outliers for each columns or all the columns together too, it depends on the data you have and how they are related. Hope it helps.

Btw, you can simply visualize the above method using a `matplotlib boxplot`. Just pass the series of data where u are doing outlier detection, it will directly do it and plot it for you. 
there are other methods, such as scikit learn [outlier detection](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html#id1)
This [blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/ways-to-detect-and-remove-the-outliers-404d16608dba) is also useful.